# Android : AndEngine pixel perfect collision GLES2?

Tags: android, collision-detection, andengine

I am using AndEngine to implement a 2d game and I am now wondering if there is actually any already implemented pixel perfect collision detection library/extension/... for AndEngine **GLES2** . I've been searching for hours now and nothing. Please do not refer me to [this](https://github.com/m5/andengine-pixel-perfect), as I've already tried it and it only works for **GLES1**. If there really isn't any already existing work I accept any idea for me to implement it - although i chose AndEngine for pixel perfect collisions, bad idea-

Thank you.

Comment: I think it should work for GLES2 too after a bit of tweaking. Maybe it's just because some methods have different parameters now.

Comment: Yea my thoughts exactly, i'm working on it :) thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **AndEngine Collision Extension:**

https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension
This is an extension that aims to bring different collision methods (perfect or approximations) to AndEngine GLES2

### **Supported Collision Methods:**

Pixel-Perfect Collision (supports: translation, scale, rotation, screw)
It also support pixel-perfect collision between pixel-perfect shapes and rectangular shapes, without the need for the latter to be a pixel-perfect shape.
Alpha values different from 0 (you set the threshold that identify if a pixel is solid or not)
You can use the Utils methods to check the performances in your app or to output the collision mask to check if it is what you need

Comment: This looks pretty good,and I see it is fairly new, thank you for sharing it. I will try it this summer and feedback.